# PDO not returning results from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am comfortable with using mysqli style php queries but am trying to use more PDO.  I think I understand most of how to use it but every now and again something comes up which throws me.

So I am doing a basic SELECT query to a mysql database and I cant get any results from the query

PHP

```
try {
    $dbhandle = new PDO("mysql:dbname = {$dbname}; host = {$dbhost}; port = {$dbport}", $dbuser, $dbpass);
} catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error when creating Database Handle. Error: " .$e;
}

$sql = $dbhandle->prepare("SELECT projectName FROM `__projects`");
$sql->execute();

$projectList = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);

$size = sizeof($projectList);
echo $size;
```

I don't understand why The array returned is empty.  Am I making a mistake.  I know the user/pass are ok as I can return results using the same query when using mysqli methods.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why the quotes around the table name? have you tried the query on phpAdmin or others db management tool?

Comment: @MarcoMura Those are at least the correct quotes for table names.

Comment: @tadman my queries do work without them, so, if those aren't special... aren't necessary =)

Comment: Does that query return anything useful when run independently of PDO? What happens when you turn on [`PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)?

Comment: @MarcoMura There's nothing wrong with having them in there, they're optional for non-keyword names. Some people prefer to quote all columns as a matter of preference.

Comment: @MarcoMura As I mentioned in the question I can get correct results from the same query through msqli_query($con, $sql) in php.  How would using a different db management tool help?

Comment: errormode_Exception comes up with Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected' but I don't see how because I have selected a database...

Comment: If you weren't using a port with `mysqli`, then don't use one in PDO. Try getting rid of `; port = {$dbport}`. You should also show us the code before that, where you're declaring those variables.

Comment: The DSN string should not have spaces in it. One continuous string: `mysql:dbname=database;host=hostname;port=3306`

Comment: Wait a minute, `mysql:dbname` that needs to be `mysql:host=...`

Comment: What has happened is that due to the spaces in the DSN string, PDO has failed to parse anything useful from the DSN and used a system default host and port, establishing a successful connection probably to localhost, but failed to parse the database name because of the space after `dbname=`.  Remove all those spaces and this should be in order.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Curious; does the order matter? OP has `mysql:dbname` etc. shouldn't that be `mysql:host=` as per what the manual states http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- I never tried anything but `host=` first, but I don't think the order matters because I have definitely used varying orders for dbname= and port= after the host.

Comment: @Fred-ii- A quick test with `dbname=` first seems to work fine.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Thanks for that Michael. Another tid bit of information I will retain.

Comment: Many Thanks guys. Have to say that's a pretty annoying syntax error.  But I guess every language has its exceptions to when it doesn't ignore whitespace...

Answer (score 1):

Try adjusting your connection statement. I'm not certain if the order will affect it, but from the documentation, it should be similar to:

```
mysql:host=localhost;port=3307;dbname=testdb
```

http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

When you want to execute a query, first make sure it will run by making it not equal or equal to false. That way you can debug your script. Try to prepare the Query alone instead of executing it right away.

The following example selects the rows in which the 'id' is 1 or 3.

```
<?php
// Connection data (server_address, database, name, poassword)
$hostdb = 'localhost';
$namedb = 'tests';
$userdb = 'username';
$passdb = 'password';

try {
// Connect and create the PDO object
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostdb; dbname=$namedb", $userdb, $passdb);
  $conn->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      // Sets encoding UTF-8

  // Define and perform the SQL SELECT query
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `sites` WHERE `id` IN(1, 3)";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);

  // If the SQL query is succesfully performed ($result not false)
  if($result !== false) {
   $cols = $result->columnCount();           // Number of returned columns

 echo 'Number of returned columns: '. $cols. '<br />';

// Parse the result set
foreach($result as $row) {
  echo $row['id']. ' - '. $row['name']. ' - '. $row['category']. ' - '. $row['link']. '<br />';
}
}

$conn = null;        // Disconnect
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```